# Swift how to run a function and change a variable in my SKScene from view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I've implemented Admob rewarded video ads into my application.

The code for the ads is in the view controller and is triggered in the game over scene.

However when I reward the user after the video has finished I want to perform an action on a variable in my SKScene.

This is the code in the view controller to reward the user:

```
func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {


    if let scene3 = GameOverMenu(fileNamed: "Gameover") {

    let oldCoin = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "COINSCORE")
    let newCoin = oldCoin + 20
    UserDefaults.standard.set(newCoin, forKey: "COINSCORE")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
   scene3.coinLabel.removeFromParent()
   scene3.createCoinScore()


    }
}
```

The User Default value does change however the coinLabel doesn't remove nor does createCoinScore trigger.

```
 var scene3: GameOverMenu!
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me!

```
 func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward) {

    if let view = self.view as! SKView? {

    if let scene3 = GameOverMenu(fileNamed: "Gameover") {

        scene3.viewController = self
        scene3.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        view.presentScene(scene3)

        let oldCoin = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "COINSCORE")
        let newCoin = oldCoin + 20
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newCoin, forKey: "COINSCORE")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        scene3.coinLabel.removeFromParent()
        scene3.createCoinScore()



    }
    }


}
```